# Databricks Delta inserts null if type conversion failed instead of throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I performed forllowing sql commands on Databricks Delta:

```
create table  default`.dem2 (col1 string)using delta;
create table  default`.dem3 (col1 date)using delta;

insert into  default.dem2  values ('QDAWDEER');
insert into  default.dem3  select * from default.dem2;
```

I expected that databricks will throw some error, but it insertes NULL value.
I used jdbc connection, I cannot access into spark commands.
This happens with databricks clusters version of that lower or equal 7.*.

Do you know may be some parameter that enables throwing exception exists?

I know about FAILFAST, but I cannot find how set it for sql statments like insert or globally on cluster.

Thank you

Comment: show the error that is thrown

Comment: @AlexOtt, I expected error like that "java.time.DateTimeException: Cannot cast QDAWDEER to DateType.", but there are no any error, and null value was inserted. But in cluster with version 8.2 this error is thrown...

Comment: That's just Spark behavior.  Cast failures return null.

Comment: @Andrew do you know how configure spark that it will throw error instead of inserting null?

Comment: @ЭльфияВалиева did you figured out how we can make spark throw an error instead of making it null?

Comment: @Be1ng_Kr1Sh unfortunately, I could not find

Comment: @ЭльфияВалиева, okay. I found this link which helped me - https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html. Basically this makes spark to follow ANSI standards.